# Error using Spot ORM in PHP

Tags: php, orm

I am using Spot ORM (http://phpdatamapper.com). 
The problem: The code terminates halfway.
There's little documentation on how to get the framework to dump errors for debugging. The code's here:

```
namespace Entity;
namespace Config;


require 'vendor/autoload.php';

echo "hello";
set_time_limit(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL);



class Post extends \Spot\Entity
{
    protected static $table = 'posts';
    public static function fields()
    {
        return [
            'id'           => ['type' => 'integer', 'primary' => true, 'autoincrement' => true],
            'title'        => ['type' => 'string', 'required' => true],
            'body'         => ['type' => 'text', 'required' => true],
            'status'       => ['type' => 'integer', 'default' => 0, 'index' => true],
            'author_id'    => ['type' => 'integer', 'required' => true],
            'date_created' => ['type' => 'datetime', 'value' => new \DateTime()]
        ];
    }
}

class Url extends \Spot\Entity
{
    protected static $table = 'urls';
    public static function fields()
    {
        return [
            'id' => ['type' => 'integer', 'primary' => true, 'autoincrement' => true],
            'domain'           => ['type' => 'text'],
            'url'        => ['type' => 'text', 'required' => false],
            'classification1'         => ['type' => 'text', 'required' => false],
            'section' => ['type' => 'string', 'required' => false],
            'status'       => ['type' => 'text'],
         /*   'author_id'    => ['type' => 'integer', 'required' => true],
            'date_created' => ['type' => 'datetime', 'value' => new \DateTime()]
        ];
    }
}

$cfg = new \Spot\Config();

$spot = new \Spot\Locator($cfg);

$cfg->addConnection('mysql', [
    'dbname' => 'sotereading',
    'user' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
]);

echo "hello";

/* this line has a problem */
$mapper = $spot->mapper('Entity\Post');
echo "hello";
$mapper->migrate();
echo "hello";
```

I used simple "echo" statements to narrow down to which line's giving the problem, and I found it (see the comment in /* */ in the code above). Why is this giving problem? It's still the same whether I used 'Entity\Post' or 'Entity\Url'.

Answer (score 0):

You have a double namespace declaration for starters so Post is actually Config\Post not Entity\Post.

```
<?php
namespace Entity;
namespace Config;

class Post { }

$x = new Post();

echo "Class is: ", get_class($x);

?>

Class is: Config\Post
```